# Deploy a Copy of the nupkg to a file share

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is it possible to output/deploy a .nupkg file that is downloaded from a teamcity server. Currently it extracts the .nupkg that is downloaded from the teamcity server. The file that is extracted into the Applications folder is stored in the Octopus\Applications.Tentacle\Packages folder but it has an internal name which is not very user friendly.

My only option at this point is to run a custom powershell script that copies the file and renames it, but this seems like a rather crude hack.

Answer (score 1):

Use the system [variables](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Variables) to access the internal values set within Octopus to find what the name and path of the nuget package you want. This [list of system variables](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/System+variables) on the Octopus Deploy site is where'd I'd start to look first. I don't know how complete the list is but there are a consider number of variables you have access to in Octopus Deploy.